# How to update a table column based on it's relation to another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "profiles". There was a column in this table called "user_id" which I have changed the name to "username" and the type from INT(11) to Varchar(255) . However the contents of this column are still numeric ids.

These ids correspond to another table called "users". That table has fields called "user_id" and "username". For each row on the "profiles" table I need to first check to see what the username field has for the id and do a look up on the users table to get the username that correcponds to that id and then update the profile table's username value for with the proper username.

**Profiles table:**

```
username | blah blah...
------------------------
1        | ...
```

**Users table:**

```
user_id | username
------------------------
1       | Joe
```

I need the value for the username field on the profiles table to be updated to "Joe".

I came up with this php script but it stops working after updating just 4 records for some reason:

```
    $sql = 'SELECT username FROM profiles';
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $id = $row['username'];
        $sql = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id = '. $id;
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $sql = "UPDATE profiles SET username = '".$row['username']."' WHERE username = $id";
            $query = mysql_query($sql);
            if(!$query) {
                echo 'error!';
            }
        }
    }
```

My script isn't all that efficient to begin with, although that's not that big an issue since the table has just 50k records. Anyway what would be a way to do this directly from mysql?

Comment: My question would be why you want to do this? You're moving from a well-structured normalised schema to something that is likely to be harder to work with and cause you problems.

Comment: @liquorvicar Yeah I decided not to. My intial reason was to select users based on username by having urls look like mysite.com/profile?user=Bob rather than having the id instead of Bob. But I didn't consider the fact that selecting by numeric id vs varchar content would be faster, id is forever unchanging, etc. So now instead I will so something like: mysite.com/profile?user=Bob&id=123, that way the name and id are both there but I am just selecting by id and having the name there for asthetic/usability reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are manipulating the $row variable inside the first loop. Obviously it does not work. Try giving the variable in inner loop a different name.

And not only that almost all the variables you are using, outside the first loop, you are using the same names inside the inner loop.

Also coming to db schema I would prefer ids to be foreign keys not usernames because querying using ids would be faster than with columns of type varchar.

One more suggestion is that there is no need to use

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
```

because there would be only one row

Answer (score 0):

As Napster said you're overwriting your **$query**, and **$row** variables. That should fix your immediate issue.

Additionally, a query inside of a while loop, inside of a while loop is absolutely terrible. No offense intended! We all have to start somewhere. But I would strongly look into how you can rewrite this with a JOIN just so you have something in your toolbelt for that next time.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think relationship between your tables is wrong, you should have a foreign key in profiles table that links to user_id in the users table, then if you change something like Joe to Michael, its corresponding record in profiles table will be updated.

**Profiles table:**

```
user_id  | blah blah...
------------------------
1        | ...
```

**Users table:**

```
user_id | username
------------------------
1       | Joe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one query

```
UPDATE profiles t1 
    INNER JOIN users t2 ON t1.username=t2.user_id 
SET t1.username=t2.username
```

Why you would want to do this is another question.